# How to correlate two text messages in facebook messenger API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I'm implementing a chat bot using [messenger API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/text-message). In a scenario like this, how to match answers with the question when both of them are in **text message** format. I can't use pattern matching here.

```
bot q1: How much is it? 
user: 250

bot q2: How many? 
user: 5
```

Is there a way to send meta data with a text message and get it as a post back. Is it required to store the last message.?

Comment: The way I handle this is I do it all locally. I keep track of the state for each user so I know what they're going to mean when they respond the next time. I also store any information for users such as the answer to bot q1 locally.

Comment: That's what am thinking of doing, since there is no other option.

Answer (score 0):

In the `message` field, in the same level of `text` field, you can define a field `metadata`, like defined [in the doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference#message) (which has a 1000 character limit):

> Custom string that will be re-delivered to webhook listeners

So it could be sth like that:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "recipient":{
    "id":"USER_ID"
  },
  "message":{
    "text":"hello, world!",
    "metadata": "my meta data"
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Comment: Which event triggered by this, Is that a post back? Can you explain little more. All i get is another text message. It doesn't have the meta data included in the previous message.

Comment: Well I just made some tests on a random bot of mine and it seems that the metadata value is never sent back, maybe you should subscribe to more fields for you webhook, I don't know. But I was almost sure that this field was implemented for that purpose ... :-/

Comment: Yes i had the same feeling, and tried , didn't work so far. Will do more testing.

Comment: same here, when you attach a metadata and send it, I dont get it back

Comment: Ya, the docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/) say that it comes back as an echo, but it definitely doesn't. Just checked that I'm getting the echo, but no meta data. I do see the message sent though in that scenario.